# Set height to same as sibling div floating next to it?

Tags: html, css

So I have 2 divs

currently

div#1 is {float:left; width:48%} and contains some gallery doodad

div#2 is {float:right; width:48%} and contains a stack of buttons

after that, within the same container a bunch of other divs and plaintext follows.

So what I would like to do is have div#1 keep doing its automatic height thing but I want div#2 height to equal div#1 so I could vertically stretch out the buttons inside.

I have no access to the structure (buried somewhere deep in the php framework) and all I got is CSS. Is this possible within my current constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply

```
display: flex;
```

to the surrounding container, then

```
float: none;
```

to `div#1`and `div#2`.

Note: This is only a viable solution if there is a parent container that does only contain these two `div`.

[Learn more about `flex`.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: hooray, I done it with {display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;} since I had more stuff in there. They seem to follow their available dimension specs when in wrap mode so 100% for 1 in row, <50% for 2 in row etc.

Comment: Remember to click the checkmark left of the answer that best helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing it's hard to say for sure, but I would think that if div#1 and div#2 both had height:100%, then when div#1 "grows" from content, so will the parent div, and because both child divs (1 & 2) are 100% height of the parent, both should grow equally.

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that support CSS3.

Set a parent DIV:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child_1"></div>
<div id="child_2></div>
</div>
```

Then in CSS set #parent_DIV to display as table (display:table). Each child DIV set to display:table-cell.
In this case the higher div will set the rule. 
Add borders to each (including parent) for trial and test it out.

I have pulled this from the head but generally that will work, including newer IE browsers.

Here it's in more details:
http://www.brenkoweb.com/tutorials/css/css-visual-formatting-model/display-property.php

And soon hopefully more examples will folow.